# Avoid body ad when click it

Tags: popups, advertisements

I visit a forum which let me download stuff. When I click anywhere it opens a new window. It is not a pop-up, it's a new window with advertisement. All the browsers can't block it because it is not a pop-up (that's what i think).

It's a little bit annoying and I want to know if there is a way to stop this thing to happen. Maybe a javascript code as a bookmark or a google chrome extension to prevent it?

Forgot: It happens only with the first click when a new page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For firefox, there's an addon named NoScript which lets you decide what url's are allowed to run scripting code on the current page (and some other goodies). Try seeing if it helps you with that issues (there are alternatives for other browsers too).

Comment: I just have installed NotScripts (Google Chrome extension) but I didn't like it so I searched more and I found that google chrome lets me make a list with sites I don't want to run javascript. Thank you for give an idea!